# Optimize JOIN with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization, left-join

I'm having trouble optimizing this query:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
LEFT JOIN c ON a.id=c.id
WHERE
   (b.c1='12345' OR c.c1='12345')
   AND (a.c2=0 OR b.c3=1)
   AND a.c4='active'
GROUP BY a.id;
```

The query takes 7s, whereas it takes 0s when only one of `b` or `c` is JOINed. The EXPLAIN:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: a
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY(id),c4,c2
          key: c4
      key_len: 1
          ref: const
         rows: 80775
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c
         type: ref
possible_keys: id_c1_unique,id
          key: id_c1
      key_len: 4
          ref: database.a.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: b
         type: ref
possible_keys: id_c1_unique,id,c1,c3
          key: id
      key_len: 4
          ref: database.a.id
         rows: 2
        Extra: Using where
```

There is always exactly 1 matching row from `b`, and at most one matching row from `c`.  It would go much faster if MySQL starting by getting the `b` and `c` rows that match the `c1` literal, then join `a` based on `id`, but it starts with `a` instead.

Details:

- MyISAM
- All columns have indexes (_unique are UNIQUE)
- All columns are NOT NULL

What I've tried:

- Changing the order of the JOINs
- Moving the WHERE conditions to the ON clauses
- Subselects for `b.c1` and `c.c1` (WHERE b.id=(SELECT b.id FROM b WHERE c1='12345'))
- USE INDEX for `b` and `c`

I understand I could do this using two SELECTs with a UNION but I need to avoid that if at all possible because of how the query is being generated.

**Edit: Add CREATE TABLEs**

`CREATE TABLE`s with the relevant columns.

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `c4` enum('active','pending','closed') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `c2` (`c2`)
  KEY `c4` (`c4`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `b` (
    `b_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `c1` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `c3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`b_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_c1_unique` (`id`,`c1`),
    KEY `c1` (`c1`),
    KEY `c3` (`c3`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `c` (
    `c_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `c1` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id_c1_unique` (`id`,`c1`),
    KEY `id` (`id`),
    KEY `c1` (`c1`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I have a stupid question: do you have indexes on all the fields you are joining?

Comment: @M.R. Yes, all columns in the query have indexes

Comment: Could you post structure of `a` ? Is `a.id` - auto-incremental field ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the query. It's just 80k rows and `GROUP BY`. If this table is both for reads and updates, you will encounter such performance problem. I hope this table is `InnoDB` ? This is bad : `Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort`. I'd do this query on a temporary table that would be `SELECT * FROM a WHERE c4 = 'active'`. I would also turn `c4` to `int`, so `1` would represent `active` state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP answering here.

What I've determined is that the behavior I'm seeing with MySQL reading the less efficient table first is an inherent issue with all LEFT JOINs where the less efficient table is on the left side.  According to [LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html) from the MySQL manual:

> MySQL implements an `A LEFT JOIN B join_condition` as follows:
>
> - Table `B` is set to depend on table `A` and all tables on which `A` depends

So:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM a
LEFT JOIN c ON a.id=c.id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

will always read `a` first, even when the query plan shows that reading `c` is more efficient.  Switching the tables causes MySQL to read from `c` first:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM c
LEFT JOIN a ON c.id=a.id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

In my case both queries return the same results.  Apparently there is something conceptual that I'm missing that requires the left side table to always be read first when doing a LEFT JOIN.  It seems to me the right side table could just as easily be read first and MySQL could still generate the same results (for certain queries, not necessarily for all LEFT JOINs).  If that were possible though that optimization probably would have been added long ago, so I guess I'm just missing the concept.

In the end switching the order of the tables wasn't a good solution for me.  I ended up merging `b` and `c` into a single table, which simplified the application and should have been done to begin with.  With a single table I can do a JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN, avoiding the issue altogether.

Another possible solution might be creating a view that incorporates both tables, thereby giving a single view to JOIN from.  I didn't test that though.

**TL;DR: Change the order of the tables to put the most efficient first (*if* the result set is the same regardless of the order).  Or merge `b` and `c` into a single table.  Or possibly create a view that combines `b` and `c`.**

Comment: For future, it appears you were hiding context of your tables with generic "a", and "b" and "c" tables from your original query.  Even if something may have "confidential" information, most people give generic things... even just like "Customer.ID" or "Account.ID", etc.  Not knowing context, its harder for others to help you (including myself).  Additionally, by KNOWING the data an finding the most efficient query (subset/key basis) SHOULD always be listed first... Additionally, adding STRAIGHT_JOIN helps to ENFORCE the order you've chosen to link tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive, but I'm pretty sure changing order of joins and moving where conditions to the on clauses doesn't matter.

I'm not sure there's enough info here to know for sure, but I'd guess that "all columns have indexes" is your problem.  For any particular query, only one index will be used per table.  So, if yo have an index on a.id, and a separate one on a.c2 and a third on a.c4.  Well, it's only going to use one.

It seems likely there are a couple columns in the indexes.  So, you only join 2 tables, it's free to use the "useful" index.

My recommendation is to examine your indexes and get them to cover the proper fields that this query is using (if possible).

a index id & c2 & c4
b index on id & c1 & c3
c index on id & c1

Answer (score 0):

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN 
      distinct a.ID
   from
      a
         join b
            on a.ID = b.ID
         left join c
            on a.id = c.id
            and c.c1 = '12345'
   where
          a.C4 = 'active'
      and ( a.c2 = 0 or b.c3 = 1 )
      and ( b.c1 = '12345' or c.c1='12345' )
```

Comment: Are you sure that `c.c1='12345'` should be in the `LEFT JOIN` condition? The original query looks like it pulls in a row from c when `b.c1='12345'`, `a.id=b.id=c.id`, and `c.c1` is arbitrary.

Comment: @Andrew: Hardly so, sir. Both queries would produce the same result, in my opinion. Rows from `c` are joined with an outer join, and so they don't matter at all if `b.c1 = '12345'`. If `b.c1 <> '12345'`, then the only things that matters is `c.c1 = '12345'`. So it's all right to add that to the join condition. In the WHERE clause I would probably change `c.c1 = '12345'` to `c.id IS NOT NULL`, though, but that might well be a matter of taste.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus, @Andriy M is correct in his explanation. I just woke up, so unable to otherwise respond earlier :)

Comment: I think I have it now. After the `distinct a.id`, you have the same set with the condition on `c.c1`, but I don't think this would be so if it were `SELECT * FROM…`.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus, I used the same "c1" condition in BOTH as that was ALL you cared about from that table.  So, if a.ID existed multiple times in the "c" table you didn't want, and I didn't want to bloat the result set... I needed to keep it in the final WHERE clause because you had a "join" to the "b" table, but EITHER "b" OR "c" could qualify.  Your abbreviated data hides what you mean to get which may have been resolved easier with REAL table/column references.